# Django sessions: changing session key when modified

Tags: python, django, session, cookies, session-cookies

I am setting up a payment gateway and am using sessions to store data across page requests. The class below is used for organizing and storing information to the session.

```
class Gateway:
  def __init__(self, session_key=None, session_name="FOO"):
    # Store session ID and name
    self.session_key    = session_key
    self.session_name   = session_name

    # Get the session
    session = SessionStore(session_key=self.session_key)

    try :
      data = session[self.session_name]
    except :
      data  = {user_id:None, checked_in:False }

    self.__dict__.update(data)

  def save(self) :
    session = SessionStore(session_key=self.session_key)
    session[self.session_name] = deepcopy(self.__dict__)
      try :
        del session['session_key']
        del session['session_name']
      except :
        pass
    session.save()
```

This view checks to see if the user is logged in. If he/she is, then he/she is redirected.  If not, he/she is asked to either login or check in as a guest.

```
def check_in(request):
  gateway = Gateway(session_key=request.session.session_key)

  if request.user.is_authenticated():
    gateway.user_id = request.user.id
    gateway.checked_in = True
    gateway.save()

    return redirect('next_step')
  else:
    login_form = FormLogin()
    if request.POST:
      data = request.POST.copy()
      if 'login' in data:
        login_form = FormLogin(data)
        if login_form.is_valid():
          user = login(request, login_form)
            if user:
              gateway.user_id = user.id
              gateway.checked_in = True
              gateway.save()
              return redirect('next_step')
        elif 'guest' in data:
          gateway.checked_in = True
          gateway.save()
          return redirect('next_step')
    return render(
      request,
      'shop/login.html',
      {
        'login_form':login_form,
      }
    )
```

The next view checks the "checked_in" variable. This is to make sure that users are not skipping over the login/checkin process. (As a side note, the function "login(request, login_form)" is a function that is works perfectly in other contexts and returns the User if it was successful and None otherwise)

```
def next_step(request):
  gateway = Gateway(session_key=request.session.session_key)

  if not gateway.checked_in:#edited 
    messages.info(request, _(u'You must specify login first.'))
    return redirect('check_in')
  else:
    #do the next step
```

Now for the problem:

Even when the user is authenticated, the "checked_in" variable is still false and causes the views to loop. A new session with a new session id is created each time that that I set the variable and save. The django docs have some explanation about the modification of sessions, but I cannot understand why new session is being created or why the session key is changing.

edit:
I am using the database backend.

Comment: I'm not sure of the point of the Gateway class. It doesn't seem to do anything except act as a holder for some data from the session, which you could much more easily access directly via the session itself.

Comment: I have not written the full class yet. It will be more useful once I can get the session to save properly.

Comment: `del session['session_key']` looks like it should be `del session[self.session_name]['session_key']`, similarly the line below.  Don't think that has anything to do with your issue.

Comment: Are you using the database session backend?

Comment: Yes, I am using the database backend. I will specify above.

Answer (score 1):

I have duplicated this bug/issue:

URL RULE

```
url(r'^test/', 'shop.views.catalog.test', name="test")
```

VIEW FUNCTION

```
def test(request) :
    key1 = request.session.session_key
    request.session['test'] = 'test'
    key2 = request.session.session_key

    raise Exception("%s : %s === %s" % (key1, key2, request.session['test']))
```

1. Clear cookies for 127.0.0.1
2. go to 127.0.0.1:8000/test/

   - Exception at /test/
     4793f2453758d7021a43a348a0f40a83 : 8568f729991e740395179c56cd37cf18 === test
3. refresh the page (w/o clearing cookies)

   - Exception at /test/
     8568f729991e740395179c56cd37cf18 : 8568f729991e740395179c56cd37cf18 === test

so until the first time my session is modified, I have a different session key... unexpected behavior. I'm also curious why.

Answer (score 1):

Django will not persist a session to the database if it has not been accessed or modified, so I believe the session_key you are using to initialise SessionStore is not actually backed by a database entry.

If this is the case: when you save your SessionStore it will be allocated a new session_key automatically [1] (as the existing key does not exist in the DB and we want to avoid session fixation [2]) and saved to the DB but the client will not be allocated this new session_key because your SessionStore is independent of request.session (which remains unmodified).

[1] https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py#L22

[2] https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/django-users/8b_6oTaXv7Q

The simple fix to test this hypothesis out would be to set request.session['kate'] = 'bob' before you initialise your Gateway class as this should force request.session to be persisted.  You might like to refactor your Gateway class so that methods that need access to the session take request.session as an argument.

Comment: I am using the session in view just before the check_in view, so the session has already been modified and is stored in the database. I still added request.session['test'] = 'test' just before I instantiate the Gateway, but the same problem occurred.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I am inexperienced and was not even aware of session fixation attacks. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas (unless request.session is being saved at the end of the request and thus overwriting your data but this would not explain the new session key).  Perhaps copious logging would point to the culprit.

Comment: Passing in request.session to methods that need it instead will save a couple of database requests and possibly avoid lost updates down the line if you (or a co-worker) starts modifying request.session as well as using your Gateway class.

Answer (score -1):

Check your `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE` value and make sure you are using **HTTPS** when `True`..

https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/issues/76

Comment: Question is for Django. this answer links to Flask... these are not the same framework.