# django session key changing upon authentication

Tags: django, django-admin, django-views

I have a Django app which records users' product choices for both authenticated users. My intention is to use the `request.session.session_key` variable to associate anonymous data with a user if they decide to register later, a la this post:

[Django storing anonymous user data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938805/django-storing-anonymous-user-data)

However, it seems that the session key changes when the user logs in/ registers so the session key can no longer be associated with the user. Is this the correct behaviour of the Django session framework. Is there a solid way to achieve the functionality I'm looking for?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [Django sessions: changing session key when modified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192904/django-sessions-changing-session-key-when-modified).

Comment: Note that this changing of session keys helps somewhat to protect against session fixation. So consider that before turning it off.

Answer (score 12):

In settings.py

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'youapp.session_backend'
```

in directory youapp in file session_backend.py

```
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore as DbSessionStore

class SessionStore(DbSessionStore):
    def cycle_key(self):
        pass
```

And session not changed after login

Comment: This worked for me, but I can't confirm it's full safety. I'm using string matching to join up session_key over the login jump.

Answer (score 5):

While the approach suggested by *nnmware* may work for this particular case, there is a better one.

Instead of just doing nothing inside `cycle_key`, we should call the super method and then save the session.

Because if you look inside the original `cycle_key` function you will see that the data from the old session is copied to the new one, but is not actually saved.

In settings.py

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'yourapp.session_backend'
```

Check that SESSION_ENGINE is pointing at a module (.py file), but not to the backend class!

Now, in your 'yourapp/session_backend.py' do the following:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore as DbSessionStore

class SessionStore(DbSessionStore):
    def cycle_key(self):
        super(SessionStore, self).cycle_key()
        self.save()
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this better, depends if you are relying on information from the old session (it's direct reference to it's object, or it's key) and in that case, you need to the old one to stay consistent, so you can bind it to the records of what you were tracking before the login event. For me, just stopping the cycle worked, hopefully not going to cause problems down the line.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions would also be to update old session data in the Session store:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore as DbSessionStore
from shop.models.cart import Cart


class SessionStore(DbSessionStore):
    def cycle_key(self):
        old_session_key = super(SessionStore, self).session_key
        super(SessionStore, self).cycle_key()
        self.save()
        Cart.objects.filter(session_key=old_session_key).update(session_key=self.session_key)
```