# How to capture the session key for an anonymous user (django 1.6)

Tags: django, django-sessions

Am trying to keep track of AnonymousUsers by their session information (if possible).

In older versions of Django, I could do something like:

```
def my_view(request):

    # in case the user wasn't logged in, create/save a session
    if not request.session.session_key:
        request.session.save()

    # would give me the key and on the next load it would persist
    session_key = request.session.session_key
```

But with 1.6 (and I've been out of the game for a while) this results in a new unique session ID each time the request is put through.  There is no persistence.  I've tried to do a little reading but am going in circles as I'm out of Django practice.

How do I have a session persist?  Do I need to write my own cookie handling?

Comment: [django session key changing upon authentication][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14757138/1978033

Comment: Thanks for the link - tried overriding the `cycle_key` method but it doesn't appear that is being called at all when an anonymous user refreshes a page ... at each refresh I am getting an empty session_key.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, after I started reading through the source code I found myself on the [global_settings.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/global_settings.py) file and found this gem:

```
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
```

When I added that to the `settings.py` file my problems were solved.  AnonymousUsers got a session_key.  Yipee!