# Session key changing after login

Tags: django, django-models, django-sessions

I am trying to save data of anonymous user if in future the user decides to become a authenticated user but it seems when I am trying to get data of anonymous user using session key after login, the key changes. I want to use the same key after login as well how can i do that? Any help will be greatly appreciated, Thank You.
Below is the views.py of the code where I am trying to retrieve data.

```py
def logincall(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        userSelected = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if userSelected:

            login(request, userSelected)
            users = User.objects.get(username=username)
            if users.is_superuser:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/staff/home/')
            else:
                cart = Temp_Cart.objects.filter(session_id=request.session.session_key).count()
                user1 = User.objects.get(username = request.user)
                if cart != 0:
                    for  i in cart:
                        percart = Cart(user = user1,quantity = i.quantity,product = i.product)
                        percart.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/home/')
```

Comment: Good question, just about to start working on this myself, might be more tricky than I thought!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978828/django-session-key-changing-upon-authentication